# Filename without extension in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, rename, file-rename

How to get the filename without the extension in AppleScript? For example:

`Penny.Dreadful.S03E01.720p.HDTV.x264-BATV.mp4`   to

```
Penny.Dreadful.S03E01.720p.HDTV.x264-BATV
```

One file to work enough for me but could be in for more file.
The following code takes the file name but with the extension. I don't want the extension. Thanks for your help.

```
try
set theNames to {}
tell application "Finder"
   repeat with i in (get selection)
       set end of theNames to name of i
   end repeat
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
set the clipboard to theNames as text
set text item delimiters to TID
end try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, instead of the try block the script checks for empty selection and the fileName is extracted by subtracting the extension if there is one.

```
set theNames to {}
tell application "Finder"
    set theSelection to selection
    if theSelection is {} then return
    repeat with anItem in theSelection
        set {name:fileName, name extension:fileExtension} to anItem
        set end of theNames to my removeExtension(fileName, fileExtension)
    end repeat
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
set the clipboard to theNames as text
set text item delimiters to TID

on removeExtension(Nm, Ex)
    if Ex is missing value or Ex is "" then return Nm
    return text 1 thru ((count Nm) - (count Ex) - 1) of Nm
end removeExtension
```

Comment: Thanks. Works is well 

Comment: can we get as output to file name at Automator?

Comment: Of course, put the code in an AppleScript action and return `theNames`. But you might use the Automator Finder selection action.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns both the file name and file extension in an array.

When renaming a file, the avantage of having both is to append a suffix to the end of a filename but before the file extension.

This method works even if the filename contains an extra dot, unlike most string-based (not Finder-based) formulas that I've seen.

```
-- Example
set pair to name_extension("my.file.txt")
set filename to item 1 of pair

-- Returns array with filename and extensions. eg. {"my.file","txt"}
on name_extension(filename)
    set rev to reverse of every character in filename as string
    set l to (length of rev) - (offset of "." in rev)
    set f1 to characters 1 thru l in filename as string
    if (f1 = filename) then
        set f2 to ""
    else
        set f2 to (characters (l + 2) thru (length of filename) in filename) as string
    end if
    return {f1, f2}
end name_extension
```